# How to proceed with this type of algorithm - getting list of products based on budget

Tags: java, algorithm

Working on a web store using Java EE. Lets say a car tuning shop. I sell kits and parts that users can buy to customise their car. I want an option such as a buyer just inputs his budget, and something like an algorithm that calculates a list of options that is possible to buy.

How can this task be accomplished?

Comment: No, not sure how fuzzy logic is related. You're looking for a best-fit algorithm, but on its own that would be useless--you'd need to pick from components targeted to what the user actually wants to do.

Comment: the parts are grouped into categories in the db. 
lets say the user can input budget for different categories. any idea of how can it be done or applied, any link or resource?

Comment: This is a known NP-hard problem and there are no known algorithms that are exact and efficient on all inputs.  Are you okay with an approximate answer?

Comment: Best-fit, bin-packing, knapsack, etc. algorithms are where I'd start.

Comment: @templatetypedef yes an approximate answer would be good enough.
@ Dave having a look at them on wikipedia. any better links?

Answer (score 3):

For each product you should get information "how much user wants this product".
If you don't want to do such survey then gather information about bestsellers in shop and provide values for each product yourself.

When each product besides cost has "value for user" then you have classical [0-1 knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

I would recommend you solving it using dynamic programming described [here](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Dynamic/knapsackdyn.htm)